# Network connection not visible in NetworkManager

Tags: networking, network-manager, 19.10

I have recently installed Ubuntu 19.10 on my new Windows laptop in dual boot. When I try to connect to a network, some wireless networks are shown but mine isn't (in Windows it does appear).

At first, my wifi card was `UNCLAIMED` so I downloaded the driver in the 'Additional' Drivers app. I can connect with Ethernet, but my WiFi network isn't shown either in the Wifi Settings or in the 'Select a wireless network' popup. I have tried rebooting several times, and using another network manager (Wicd).

I am new to Linux, please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try connect your laptop by wire (using wired network port or USB-Ethernet adapter) and reinstall Ubuntu, allowing the installer to download components from the Internet.

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu, and it didn't work, so I carried out further research concerning my WiFi card (Realtek RTL8821CE) and finally found out how to install the right driver (thanks to post #1071299), which isn't proposed by Ubuntu by default.